# Name cannot begin with the '?' character, hexadecimal value 0x3F

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

I'm upgrading some old solutions and there are few projects ran into the following error after the auto-migrate and listed in the migration report

> Name cannot begin with the '?' character, hexadecimal value 0x3F. Line
>   1, position 3.

I research a bit on the internet but can't find the result which the character is ?.

I checked

> Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20
>   Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24

But the solutions don't seem to fit my case.

I look into the csproj and do the xml valid by online tool, everything seems fine.

The failed projects seem to be either ASP.NET site or SOAP web service.

Content in one of the csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VisualStudioProject>
  <CSHARP ProjectType="Web" ProductVersion="7.10.3077" SchemaVersion="2.0" ProjectGuid="{9CCCD8A9-8CEF-4FFF-80C6-8123FC554342}" SccProjectName="SAK" SccLocalPath="SAK" SccAuxPath="SAK" SccProvider="SAK">
    <Build>
      <Settings ApplicationIcon="" AssemblyKeyContainerName="" AssemblyName="PortalHome" AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile="" DefaultClientScript="JScript" DefaultHTMLPageLayout="Grid" DefaultTargetSchema="IE50" DelaySign="false" OutputType="Library" PreBuildEvent="" PostBuildEvent="" RootNamespace="PortalHome" RunPostBuildEvent="OnBuildSuccess" StartupObject="">
        <Config Name="Debug" AllowUnsafeBlocks="false" BaseAddress="285212672" CheckForOverflowUnderflow="false" ConfigurationOverrideFile="" DefineConstants="DEBUG;TRACE" DocumentationFile="" DebugSymbols="true" FileAlignment="4096" IncrementalBuild="false" NoStdLib="false" NoWarn="" Optimize="false" OutputPath="bin\" RegisterForComInterop="false" RemoveIntegerChecks="false" TreatWarningsAsErrors="false" WarningLevel="4" />
        <Config Name="Release" AllowUnsafeBlocks="false" BaseAddress="285212672" CheckForOverflowUnderflow="false" ConfigurationOverrideFile="" DefineConstants="TRACE" DocumentationFile="" DebugSymbols="false" FileAlignment="4096" IncrementalBuild="false" NoStdLib="false" NoWarn="" Optimize="true" OutputPath="bin\" RegisterForComInterop="false" RemoveIntegerChecks="false" TreatWarningsAsErrors="false" WarningLevel="4" />
      </Settings>
      <References>
        <Reference Name="System" AssemblyName="System" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.dll" />
        <Reference Name="System.Drawing" AssemblyName="System.Drawing" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.Drawing.dll" />
        <Reference Name="System.Data" AssemblyName="System.Data" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.Data.dll" />
        <Reference Name="System.Web" AssemblyName="System.Web" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.Web.dll" />
        <Reference Name="System.XML" AssemblyName="System.Xml" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.XML.dll" />
        <Reference Name="System.Web.Mobile" AssemblyName="System.Web.Mobile" HintPath="..\..\..\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\System.Web.Mobile.dll" />
      </References>
    </Build>
    <Files>
      <Include>
        <File RelPath="AssemblyInfo.cs" BuildAction="Compile" />
        <File RelPath="Default.aspx" BuildAction="Content" />
        <File RelPath="Default.aspx.cs" DependentUpon="Default.aspx" SubType="ASPXCodeBehind" BuildAction="Compile" />
        <File RelPath="Global.asax" SubType="Component" BuildAction="Content" />
        <File RelPath="Global.asax.cs" DependentUpon="Global.asax" SubType="Code" BuildAction="Compile" />
        <File RelPath="Global.asax.resx" DependentUpon="Global.asax.cs" BuildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
        <File RelPath="Web.config" BuildAction="Content" />
      </Include>
    </Files>
  </CSHARP>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

I think I found a clue.

When I double click the csproj it will create a tmp file like `vs2D44.tmp`. Which is xml format and contains

```
<??>
<VisualStudioProject>
    <CSHARP
        ProductVersion = "7.10.3077"
        SchemaVersion = "2.0"
something ...
```

That I think is where the error message actually from. But still, don't know why or how to solve it.

Comment: Line 1 should look like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.  Position 2, not 3.  You'll get this error when it got mangled to, say, `<??xml ...>`.  Use a hex viewer to find out what it really looks like.

Comment: @HansPassant line 1 of csproj is the same as what you type instead of `<??xml`. Could you elaborate a bit more about hex viewer part? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Just google "windows hex viewer" to find hits.  HxD is fine.  It lets you see the actual bytes in the file, including the ones that don't produce a visible character.

Answer (score 0):

try by making CheckCharacters = false in XmlReaderSettings. See below for e.g. -

```
using System.Xml;
XDocument doc = null
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false };
using (XmlReader reader = //xml) { doc = XDocument.Load(reader); }
```

Then continue with reading the XML.

This should stop the XML Reader to check whether a given XML have characters that are 'illegal' and if it does - throw an exception. This is true by default.

Find more info on legal characters, standards and other info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: before reading the XML. e.g. put this line of code and then continue with - using (XmlReader reader = //xml) { //do something; }

Comment: I didn't read the xml. I run into this while trying to open an old csproj by VS2017. The error shows on migration report.

Comment: I would recommend you validate your web.config, app.config files (check every row). Or use 'find' and look for the question mark in you csproj.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a file that *"is XML format and contains `<??>`"*.

Well, that's a contradiction. If it contains `<??>` then it's not in XML format.

When you get a file containing broken XML, you should do the same as if you buy a set of broken glasses: take them back to the supplier and ask for an exchange or a refund. If you can't do that, you'll have to find your own way of repairing the damage. There are tools around that may help you, like TagSoup, but by their nature they won't handle all possible ways of breaking the XML rules.